# Python Matrix Factorization

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matrix-multiplication, canopy

I have the following code in python

```
###############################################################################

"""
@INPUT:
    R     : a matrix to be factorized, dimension N x M
    P     : an initial matrix of dimension N x K
    Q     : an initial matrix of dimension M x K
    K     : the number of latent features
    steps : the maximum number of steps to perform the optimisation
    alpha : the learning rate
    beta  : the regularization parameter
@OUTPUT:
    the final matrices P and Q
"""
def matrix_factorization(R, P, Q, K, steps=5000, alpha=0.0002, beta=0.02):
    Q = Q.T
    for step in xrange(steps):
        for i in xrange(len(R)):
            for j in xrange(len(R[i])):
                if R[i][j] > 0:
                    eij = R[i][j] - numpy.dot(P[i,:],Q[:,j])
                    for k in xrange(K):
                        P[i][k] = P[i][k] + alpha * (2 * eij * Q[k][j] - beta * P[i][k])
                        Q[k][j] = Q[k][j] + alpha * (2 * eij * P[i][k] - beta * Q[k][j])
        eR = numpy.dot(P,Q)
        e = 0
        for i in xrange(len(R)):
            for j in xrange(len(R[i])):
                if R[i][j] > 0:
                    e = e + pow(R[i][j] - numpy.dot(P[i,:],Q[:,j]), 2)
                    for k in xrange(K):
                        e = e + (beta/2) * ( pow(P[i][k],2) + pow(Q[k][j],2) )
        if e < 0.001:
            break
    return P, Q.T

###############################################################################
```

The link to this code is as follows :
http://www.quuxlabs.com/blog/2010/09/matrix-factorization-a-simple-tutorial-and-implementation-in-python/

code works properly for small matrix but I have two large matrices P(15715
,203)  and Q(203,16384) and when i try to execute this code on P and Q it gives me following error

```
K=203

matrix_factorization(R, P, Q, K)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-00b8211f2507> in <module>()
----> 1 matrix_factorization(R, P, Q, K)

/Users/ajinkyachandrakantbobade/Desktop/random_choicefile/trial.py in matrix_factorization(R, P, Q, K, steps, alpha, beta)
     52             for j in xrange(len(R[i])):
     53                 if R[i][j] > 0:
---> 54                     eij = R[i][j] - numpy.dot(P[i,:],Q[:,j])
     55                     for k in xrange(K):
     56                         P[i][k] = P[i][k] + alpha * (2 * eij * Q[k][j] - beta * P[i][k])

/Users/ajinkyachandrakantbobade/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   1967             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   1968         else:
-> 1969             return self._getitem_column(key)
   1970 
   1971     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/Users/ajinkyachandrakantbobade/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _getitem_column(self, key)
   1974         # get column
   1975         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 1976             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   1977 
   1978         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/Users/ajinkyachandrakantbobade/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1087         """ return the cached item, item represents a label indexer """
   1088         cache = self._item_cache
-> 1089         res = cache.get(item)
   1090         if res is None:
   1091             values = self._data.get(item)

TypeError: unhashable type
```

Can anyone please help regarding this error ?

Answer (score 0):

The size of the matrices you are trying to multiply is too big, and you don't have enough memory to complete the calculation. A few things that could help:

- get more RAM
- if your matrix contains lots of 0, you could try using sparse matrices. They are regular matrices that only store elements that exhibit a value different from zero. [The documentation of scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) will give you some information on that.
- it seems that you are already using python 64bit but if not this would work better than python 32bit

Comment: Based on the directory naming (i.e., Canopy_64), the OP is using 64-bit python.

Comment: Thank you for your comment .There are many zeros in resulting matrix I read the documentation but could not find way on how to create sparse matrix of such a huge matrix is there any other document  that i should refer that will solve the Question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scipy package (e.g. scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(arg1[, shape, dtype, copy]))
to convert your matrix into a sparse matrix. This will allow to work with using MF on a bigger dataset without running into computational problems.

For an implementation of the method I used the non-negative matrix factorization explained by Jason Feriante on 
https://github.com/jferiante/Collaborative-Filtering-Machine-Learning/blob/master/python/nmf-learn.py